# Lixo de memória ao apontar um ponteiro

Tags: c, c++, ponteiro, grafo

Na tentativa de implementar um grafo de matriz adjacente, eu criei a função criarVertice no qual seria criada uma nova "matriz" e o conteúdo do grafo seria copiado para ela, adicionando as novas posições. Porém, ao chamar essa função e imprimir o novo grafo, a saída contém vários lixo de memória. Aonde está o erro?

```
class GrafosMatriz{
    public:
     int *grafo;
     int tam;

GrafosMatriz(int tam){
    this->tam = tam;
    grafo = new int[tam*tam];
        for(int i = 0 ; i < tam*tam; i++)
                grafo[i] = 0;

}
void criarVertice(){
    tam++;
    int *aux = new int[tam*tam]; //matriz aux declarada com n+1
        for(int i = 0 ; i < tam*tam; i++){
            aux[i] = 0;
        }

        for(int i = 0,  j = 0; i < tam*tam - tam; i++){ //Passar pela matriz nova de tamanho n+1, sem passar na ultima linha
            if(i%tam != 0){  // pular a ultima coluna da matriz
                j++;
               aux[i] = grafo[j];
            }
        }

        grafo = aux;
        delete aux;

}
```

Comment: Quando se cria uma variavel sem dar um valor a ela vai ter sempre lixo, pois vai ter um numero aletorio. Logo quando se cria a matriz e não se introduz nenhum valor vai ocorrer isso. É isso que está a falar?

Comment: Mas "aux" foi preenchida com zeros, ela tem valor. Mas  ao apontar "grafo" para "aux", aparece lixo de memória

Comment: com o `tam` incrementado, você está acessando índices inexistentes no `grafo`.

Comment: Mas eles são existentes em aux, e grafo passa a apontar para aux, não? Estou enganado?

Comment: Voce está fazendo grafo apontar para aux e não copiando, e logo em seguida voce faz del aux.
Aquele memset apos alocar espaço para grafo é desnecessario, a funcao new ja inicializa com 0.